# BCD arithmetic operations

Tags: c, math, bcd

I have written a function that converts a double to a BCD (BCD: Save each digit of the double as an unsigned char, in addition save the complete length, the fractional length (part behind the floating point) and the sign of the double number).
I use the following struct

```
struct bcd_number 
{ 
unsigned int length; 
unsigned int fractional; 
signed char sign; 
unsigned char *digits; 
};
```

And thats the double to BCD function:

```
    struct bcd_number* double2bcd(double x) 
{ 
    char tmp[512]; 
    struct bcd_number* bcd = malloc (sizeof(struct bcd_number)); 
    
    int a = x;  
    double before = a;
    double fractional;
    fractional = x-(long)x;

 
    bcd->digits = malloc (512);
 
    char* z = (char*) bcd->digits; 


    sprintf (tmp,"%g",fabs(before));
   
    bcd->length = strlen(tmp); 
    bcd->sign = (before < 0) ? '-' : '+';
    
    for (size_t i=0; i<bcd->length; ++i)
     { *z++ = tmp[i] - '0'; } 

    sprintf (tmp,"%g",fabs(fractional)); 

    for (size_t i = strlen(tmp)-1; i!=0; --i) 
    if (tmp[i] != '0') 
    { tmp[i+1] = 0; break; } 


    bcd->fractional = strlen(tmp+2);
    bcd->length += bcd->fractional; 


    for (char* t = tmp + 2; *t; *z++ = *t++ - '0'); 
        bcd->digits = realloc (bcd->digits, bcd->length); 



    return bcd; 
}
```

That works perfect.

And I had also added the ability to perform addition/subtraction (Complete source code: http://pastebin.com/HR70VukM) but now I want to perform multiplication and division.
But the problem is that there are only chars as digits (I don't want to change that). I now that must be like 'multiplication on the paper' (classical way without calculator) but I have the idea that it must be like addition with the modulo operator. On the other hand I have no idea how to implement it with chars with modulo. Any ideas or hints?

Comment: You really should remove the initial `malloc()`. Do the conversion to a temporary buffer in the function, then `malloc()` once you know the correct size, removing the need to `realloc()`. Even better, decide on a maximum static size and always use that, since you also store the lengths. Many small (10-30 bytes) allocations can be very costly and inefficient to manage.

Comment: It's not really clear what the specific question is.  If you are asking "how do I perform [long multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_multiplication#Long_multiplication) in decimal?", then the answer is "the same you'd do it by hand".

Comment: Okay I want to write a function (for example: struct bcd_number* multiplication (struct bcd_number *a, struct bcd_number *b) that preforms the multiplication but I've problems with the implementation of the "the same you'd do it by hand"-way.

Comment: @Kossi: Can you show the code you have so far, and point out where it doesn't work?  Or alternatively, give a numerical example that you don't know how to handle.

Comment: Part of the solution to *multiplication the same way as you do it by hand* is to store, and use, a look-up table for all single-digit multiplications, what I would call a *times table*.

Comment: Is this some kind of homework, or do you just need to do arbitrary precision maths? If the latter, then you should seriously consider using an existing library, like [GNU MPC](http://www.multiprecision.org/).

Comment: FYI, you've created some sort of hybrid between ASCII and BCD.  In standard BCD, the number `12345` would be encoded in 3 bytes as hex `01 23 45`.  In your hybrid encoding, you have these 5 bytes:  `01 02 03 04 05`.

Comment: @indiv: It's not really "hybrid", it's just a different choice of how many bits to reserve for each decimal digit.

Comment: @Oli:  Yeah, hybrid was probably a poor choice but I meant to convey that this scheme really just saves you from having to subtract '0' when using a digit if you had just left it in ASCII form in the first place.  If I was using this in a library, I'd be surprised that `99` wasn't BCD `0x99`.  But hey maybe I'm the oddball here for expecting packed BCD, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you ever wanted to know about BCD can be found at the [General Decimal Arithmetic](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/) web site.

For multiplication, you will need a primitive routine that multiples two digits together yielding a two digit result. Add this intermediate result to the appropriate position in the answer. Besides having a "multiplication table," finding this "appropriate position" is the crux of "the same you'd do it by hand" method.